# How to subtract the result of a query with a result of another query in c# linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get records from `investment` and calculate the sum of `Amount` from `investment_Line` where `investment_Line.ParentID==investment.Investment`.

Subtract the Amount `Calculte==d.Amount-Answer`

```
var a = (from investment in _entities.Investments
        where investment.StatusID == 4
        select new
        {
            RefNo = investment.RefNo,
            InvestedAmount = investment.InvestedAmount,
            Amount = investment.InvestedAmount + investment.ProfitAmount,
            InvestmentID = investment.ID,
            UserID = investment.UserID,
            StatusID = investment.StatusID,

        }).ToList();

if (a.Count() != 0)
{
    foreach (var row in a)
    {
        var count = (_entities.Investment_Line.Where(x => x.ParentID == row.InvestmentID)).Count();
        if(count != 0)
        {
            var _group = _entities.Investment_Line.Where(x => x.ParentID == row.InvestmentID).GroupBy(g => g.ParentID).Select(s => new { SumAmount = s.Sum(sum => sum.Amount) });
            double answer = double.ConvertToDouble(_group.Select(x => x.SumAmount));
            var data = (from d in a
                        select new Search.ReadyInvestmentList
                        {
                            RefNo = d.RefNo,
                            InvestedAmount = d.InvestedAmount,
                            TotalAmount = d.Amount,
                            InvestmentID = d.InvestmentID,
                            UserID = d.UserID,
                            StatusID = d.StatusID,
                            Calculate = d.Amount-answer
                        }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**Investment table**

```
+---+--------------------------+--------+-------------+----------------+--------+-------------+----------+
|ID | CreateDate               | UserID |  RefNo      | InvestedAmount | Growth%| ProfitAmount|StatusID  |
+---+--------------------------+--------+-------------+----------------+--------+-------------+----------+
|1  | 2017-01-11 16:39:06.483  | 1      |  BPWM57G2Q2 | 20000          | 30     | 6000        | 4        |
|2  | 2017-01-11 16:49:18.850  | 2      |  BPWM56H2T0 | 10000          | 30     | 3000        | 4        |
|3  | 2017-01-11 17:15:02.667  | 3      |  BPWM56G2L0 | 500            | 30     | 1500        | 1        |
|4  | 2017-01-12 20:22:02.160  | 5      |  BPWM68L2I0 | 500            | 30     | 150         | 2        |
|5  | 2017-01-12 20:25:03.160  | 5      |  BPWM63F2I5 | 2000           | 30     | 600         | 4        |
+---+--------------------------+--------+-------------+----------------+--------+-------------+----------+
```

**Investment_Line table**

```
+----+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------+------------+-----------+
| ID | InvestmentID| InvestorID| AssistorID| Amount| RefNo      |  ParentID |
+----+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------+------------+-----------+
| 1  | 2           | 2         | 1         | 10000 | BPWM56H2T0 |  1        |
| 2  | 3           | 3         | 1         | 5000  | BPWM56G2L0 |  1        |
| 3  | 4           | 5         | 3         | 500   | BPWM68L2I0 |  3        |
+----+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------+------------+-----------+
```

**Required Output**

```
+----+---------+-----------+-------+---------------+------------+-----------+
| InvestmentID | RefNo     | UserID| InvestedAmount| TotalAmount| Calculate |
+--------------+--------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
| 1            | BPWM57G2Q2| 1     | 20000         | 26000      | 15000     |
| 2            | BPWM56H2T0| 2     | 10000         | 13000      | 0         |
| 5            | BPWM63F2I5| 5     | 2000          | 2600       | 0         |
+----+---------+-----------+-------+-------------- +------------+-----------+
```

What is the best way to do this?
Please help.

Comment: Some of the column names you're referring to in your LINQ queries as well as your question don't seem to match with the column names of the sample tables you've provided, or appear to be missing such as ActiveYN.

Comment: @MattD I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Your code will have bad performance if there will be many records in master detail table. Because you will have `masterRecordCount * DetailRecordCount` nested loop. So it will be better if you group and join in one query

```
var calculatedlist = from I in _entities.Investments
            join IL in _entities.Investment_Line on I.ID equals IL.ParentID
            group IL by new { I.ID } into g
            select new { 
                InvestmentID  = g.Key,
                RefNo      = g.Max(m => m.I.RefNo), 
                UserID = g.Max(m => m.I.UserID) ,
                InvestedAmount = g.Max(m => m.I.InvestedAmount) ,
                TotalAmount = g.Max(m => m.I.InvestedAmount) + g.Max(m => m.I.ProfitAmount),
                Calculate  = g.Max(m => m.I.InvestedAmount) + g.Max(m => m.I.ProfitAmount) - g.Sum(m => m.IL.Amount)
            };
```